# Add space around each / using Humanizer or Regex

Tags: c#, regex, humanizer

I have a string like the following:

```
var text = @"Some text/othertext/ yet more text /last of the text";
```

I want to normalize the spaces around each slash so it matches the following:

```
var text = @"Some text / othertext / yet more text / last of the text";
```

That is, one space before each slash and one space after.  How can I do this using Humanizer or, barring that, with a *single* regex?  **Humanizer is the preferred solution.**

I'm able to do this with the following *pair* of regexes:

```
var regexLeft = new Regex(@"\S/");    // \S matches non-whitespace
var regexRight = new Regex(@"/\S");
var newVal = regexLeft.Replace(text, m => m.Value[0] + " /");
newVal = regexRight.Replace(newVal, m => "/ " + m.Value[1]);
```

Comment: `\S*/\S*` replace with ` / `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
  var text = @"Some text/othertext/ yet more text /last of the text";

  // Some text / othertext / yet more text / last of the text 
  string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s*/\s*", " / ");
```

slash surrounded by zero or more spaces replaced by slash surrounded by exactly one space.

Comment: A slower alternative is `Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\S)(?=/)|(?<=/)(?=\S)", " ")`, regexhero.net benchmark shows it is 2.5 times slower. Still, does the similar job: finds places where `/` is preceded/followed with a non-whitespace and adds a space there. If the taks was to keep existing spaces, this one would be preferable, but for normalizing, `\s*/\s*` is the one that should be used.

Comment: I want to wait a few hours to see if a Humanizer solution pops up.  If none does, I intend to mark this as the accepted answer.